# How to specify DOT language "rank" attribute for set of vertices in QuickGraph?

Tags: c#, graphviz, rank, subgraph, quickgraph

basically what I want to do is to visualize dependencies between iterations. To make this happen I need to draw my nodes in rows and columns so they form one big rectangle. I managed to do this in C code with GraphViz by using Agraph_t *agsubg(Agraph_t*, char*, int) function, setting rank attribute and making invisible edges but I need to make this in C#.  So my question is how to make subgraphs/clusters using QuickGraph. Or maybe there is a way to make this work without subgraphs.